# $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\theta,\sigma^2)$, $\pi(\theta,\sigma^2)\propto 1/\sigma^2$, $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\rho X,\sigma^2)$, $\rho$ fixed. $f(y|x)$?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, uninformative-prior

like in the title I have the following question.

Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\theta,\sigma^2)$ with the improper prior $\pi(\theta,\sigma^2)\propto 1/\sigma^2$ and consider $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\rho X,\sigma^2)$ with $\rho$ fixed and known.

I want to know the density $f(y|x)$ of the posterior predictive distribution of $Y$ given $X$, but at some point I don't know how to go further dealing with the improper prior.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please identify the "some point" at which you are stuck.

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course!
Problems actually arise already when I try to compute the posterior, since I don't know which distribution that should be.
I came up with
$\pi(\theta,\sigma^2|x)\propto \frac{1}{\sigma^3} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma})^2\right)$

Comment: I also tried to compute the posterior predictive distribution of $Y$ given $X$ directly via
$f(y|x)=\int f(y|x,\theta,\sigma^2)\pi(\theta,\sigma^2|x)~d(\theta,\sigma^2)$, but also there I can't compute it